# Has the color of child Spock’s ears in the Star Trek reboot ever been discussed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, spock

I always found something vaguely annoying about a production detail left out in the scene where the young Spock is speaking with his father, Sarek...

You can clearly see that Spock has a split lip, with the suggestion of green blood. Yet no one appears to have taken the time to digitally color adjust the color of Spock's ears from red to green. Since they were backlit, you could see the vasculature of the young actor's ears. A minor detail to be sure, but you would think someone would've caught that.

Has there ever been any discussion about that slip up?

Comment: You could even expand a bit on this and ask why Vulcan's aren't tinted green overall. Also keep in mind that he's no pure Vulcan, so that might be some side effect of being half human.

Comment: Related Question: [Why are Vulcan lips Human-reddish instead of green?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16706/2565).

Comment: The answer to the question this is supposed to be a duplicate of is, that that time it was probably to expensive. That is no answer to the question, if they considered it to change it for the relaunch.

Comment: Not a dupe of the question Bitmask linked. The original asks for the in-universe reason for the color in the original series. This is asking about a possible error in the reboot.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the answers to [Why are Vulcan lips Human-reddish instead of green?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green), and on the Star Trek wiki article for [Vulcans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan#Physiology), it is definitely canonical that Vulcan blood is copper-based, and hence it is possible that it has a more complicated relationship with color than human blood.

An earth-based example of a copper-based blood (also referred to in the wiki) is ***Hemocyanin***, found in Molluscs and Arthropods.

> Hemocyanin is colorless when deoxygenated and dark blue when oxygenated. The blood in the circulation of these creatures,... is grey-white to pale yellow, and it turns dark blue when exposed to the oxygen in the air, as seen when they bleed. This is due to change in color of hemocyanin when it is oxidized.

While speculative, it seems not outside likelihood that the behaviour of the Vulcans' blood color is similar to the above mechanism - being a different color when in circulation and only turning bright green when exposed to air. Green, after all, (like the blue of hemocyanin) is also a color found in oxygenated copper and copper salts.

So, it could be that the reason why Spock's ears (and skin and lips, as mentioned in the previously linked question) are red, while his split lip bleeds green, is because his blood experiences changes in color when exposed to the air.

Which would mean that the color of child!Spock's ears in the Reboot are as expected.