# How Green are Vulcans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, vulcan

I have read that the creators of TOS originally wanted to give Spock red skin but the red makeup they used looked bad in black and white TV.

And they they considered green makeup for Spock.

So did Leonard Nimoy wear green makeup in *Star Trek: The Original Series?*

The question "Why are Vulcan lips human-reddish instead of Green?" and its answers assume that Nimoy did not wear any greenish face makeup in *Star Trek*.

[Why are Vulcan lips Human-reddish instead of green?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green?rq=1)[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green?rq=1)

The cover illustration for *Star Trek* 1967 by James Blish has a greenish faced Spock.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Star+trek+James+blish+1967&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjysqG8k8vUAhUIbz4KHaSCBEYQ_AUIBigB&biw=1280&bih=845#imgrc=fk4eK7SDwlwXuM:[2](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a9/03/f0/a903f09265959b2e7ae051b542237010.jpg)

In pictures of Spock from *Star Trek: The Animated Series* he sometime seems to have a Caucasian complexion and sometimes a slightly greenish complexion.  Spock never looks as green as an Orion slave girl, but sometimes looks like he could be related to the Green Girl of Woolpit. If the makers of *Star Trek: The Animated Series* deliberately gave Spock a slightly greenish complexion it was very well done considering that director Hal Sutherland had a form of color blindness.

[Spock from The Animated Series](https://www.google.com/search?q=Spock+star+trek+the+animated+series&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj22_KXzsjUAhVIHD4KHXqbBSsQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=894)

But I have been watching *Star Trek: The Original Series* on the Heroes & Icons channel and Spock's face does seem faintly greenish in some scenes, especially when standing next to a Caucasian Human.

According to Memory Alpha:

> Most Vulcans had straight, glossy dark brown or, more commonly, black hair and pale skin with a very subtle greenish tinge, much as the skin of Humans of European descent had a very subtle reddish or pinkish tinge.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan#Physiology[3](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan#Physiology)

The original question by bitmask in "Why are Vulcan lips Human-Reddish instead of Green?" says that Caucasian Humans have lips that are a brighter pink than their paler skin on the rest of the face.  And thus Spock could have been given green lips to show that he was a green-blooded Vulcan.  And it asks why that wasn't done.

[Why are Vulcan lips Human-reddish instead of green?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green)[4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green)

Thus bitmask believes that Leonard Nimoy as Spock didn't wear any green makeup on his face and thus on his lips.

The accepted answer by G.Vegt says:

> As the link you provide indicates, caucasian-equivalent Vulcans have not only green blood, they have green skin. (In a caucasian, most of the skin colouration is from the blood, this is why sick caucasian people tend to become so pale as their blood withdraws from their skin.)
>
> Thus I would expect that while they may have wanted to colour the lips and skin green, it was not feasible in the budgets of the time to do more than just colour the lips. The combination of pink with green is aesthetically unpleasing to many people, so they probably decided to avoid combining pink skin with green lips, and accept it as a limitation.
>
> Over time, people have gotten used to the skin tone of Vulcans as portrayed in the series, and as such it would be economically infeasible to use modern technology to provide the correct skin tone and lip colour.

[Why are Vulcan lips Human-reddish instead of green?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green)[4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16706/why-are-vulcan-lips-human-reddish-instead-of-green)

So he says:

1) Officially most Vulcans have pale greenish skin and slightly brighter greenish lips.

2) Probably the makers of TOS couldn't afford to color more than Spock's lips.

3) Pink and green are clashing colors so it would have looked bad for Spock to have pinkish skin and greenish lips.  So the creators of TOS didn't color Spock's lips.

4) And so people have become used to seeing Vulcan with pinkish skin and lips.

But there is some evidence that Leonard Nimoy may have worn faintly greenish face make up as Spock in *Star Trek: The Original Series*.

So I ask if bitmask and G.Vegt are correct in saying that Spock was not depicted with faintly greenish skin in *Star Trek: The Original Series* or if Leonard Nimoy as Spock did wear faintly greenish face makeup?

Comment: This green |-------------|

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you're looking for that wasn't given in the question you linked.

Comment: I have edited my question to show that I am asking if Bitmask and G.Vegt were correct in their opinion that Nimoy did not wear any green makeup as Spock or if he did wear greenish face makeup in TOS.